# Should I use console.time to time the execution of a function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Im expirementing with my parsing function in Node.js and was wondering if the console.time was a relatively reliable way to measure the time it takes to execute, Im looking for about ±10ms accuracy. Also I was wondering if there was a way to set the format of console.time, right now its returning the result in milliseconds.

Comment: Why are you needing to time a function?  Is this for profiling, or are you wanting to wait until a function returns?

Comment: Im not sure what profiling means. Im just trying to get an idea of how long its taking to finish uploading some data to my server.

Comment: [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime) is probably more accurate (FWIW, [this](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/ef4344311e19a4f73c031508252b21712b22fe8a/lib/console.js#L79-L91) is how `console.time{End}()` are implemented).